# Angular common function should put module or parent component

Tags: angular

My project like this now.
[image]
Test.component is the parent component with two child components

Then both child components load a child-more component

Question is

My child-1, child-2, child-more components

There have many common functions and variables

I should create a share.module and put the common functions and variables here.

or just put in the parent component(test.component)

Which method would be better?

or is there any better way?

Comment: create an abstract base class that they all extend possibly?

Comment: Or just .ts file with exported functions that you can then import in to whatever component files you want. Common variables is a different story, that is probably best addressed with a common base class. However, if you mean sharing values across component instances then you should create a service with those values.

Comment: Another way would be creating a service for common functionality.

Answer (score 0):

> I should create a share.module and put the common functions and
>   variables here.

If you want to create a class where common variables are kept and these variables are consumed, the following example might give you an idea.
https://angular-c8shbr.stackblitz.io/ and edit link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c8shbr

```js
export class General
{
  public static listCountry={"90":"Turkey","91":"Other Country"};
  

  public static getCountryByFilter(field)
  {
    return this.listCountry[field];
  }
}
```